# Putting search result into a table js

Tags: javascript, css, html

so at the moment my application uses `document.write` to give search results to a user however instead I would like the results to be outputted to user in a table in `<div class="main">` however I don't want the table to be seen at the beginning only when it's giving results, how can that be done? Thanks for help in advance! :)

https://jsfiddle.net/48prjb62/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- This is standard HTML code that tells the browser it is a HTML page-->
<html lang="en-GB"> <!-- This tells the browser what language html is using-->
<head> <!-- standard html tag -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Any Phone4You</title>
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
<h1>Any Phone4You</h1>
</header>
<div class="main">
</div>
<div class="search">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select phone brand</legend>
            <label for="sony">Sony</label>
            <input type="radio" name="brand" class="phone" value="Sony">
            <label for="motorola">Motorola</label>
            <input type="radio" name="brand" class="phone" value="Motorola">
            <label for="samsung">Samsung</label>
            <input type="radio" name="brand" class="phone" value="Samsung">
            <label for="apple">Apple</label>
            <input type="radio" name="brand" class="phone" value="Apple">
            <label for="lg">LG</label>
            <input type="radio" name="brand" class="phone" value="LG">
        </fieldset>
        <label for="phone_model">Model</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone_model" />
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select a network</legend>
            <label for="zmobile">Z-Mobile</label>
            <input type="radio" name="net" class="network" value="Z-Mobile">
            <label for="o3">O3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="net" class="network" value="O3">
            <label for="fodavone">Fodavone</label>
            <input type="radio" name="net" class="network" value="Fodavone">
            <label for="nn">NN</label>
            <input type="radio" name="net" class="network" value="NN">
        </fieldset>
        <input type="range" name="rating" min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="50" id="range.slider" />
        <span id="range">0</span><br /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check.minutes" id="check.text" value="Unlimited">Unlimited
        <input type="range" name="rat" min="0" max="5000" value="0" step="100" id="slider.range" />
        <span id="rata">0</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check.text" id="check.text" value="Unlimited">Unlimited
        <label for="internet">Data</label>
        <input type="text" id="internet" />
        <label for="upcost">Upfront Cost</label>
        <input type="number" id="upcost" />
        <label for="month_cost">Monthly Cost</label>
        <input type="number" id="month_cost" />
        <label for="contract_length">Contract Length</label>
        <input type="number" id="contract_length" />
        <input type="button" value="click me" id="search">
    </form>
</div>
<footer>@Copyright Reserved by Przemyslaw Wojtas @2015-2016 !Do not copy!</footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.margin{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.textalign{
    text-align: left;
}
.textalign2{
    text-align: center;
}
.header{
    top: 2%;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(39,133,203);
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;

}
h1{
    left: 5%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    margin: 0;
}
.main{
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    height: 850px;
    background-color: rgb(98,204,255);
}
footer{
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif; 
}
fieldset{
    display: block;
}
form{
        font-size: 16px;
    width:100%;
        border: 1px solid;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000000;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}/* this will style my form */
input, select, textarea{
        display: block;
        margin:2%;
}/* this style all input, select and textarea tags */
input{
    border:2px solid #CCC;
    width: 70%;
        margin-top: 2%;
}/* further styling to input tag */
textarea{
    width:50%;
    border:3px solid #CCC;
}/* further styling to textarea tag */

.search{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 850px;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: rgb(39,133,203);
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

JS:

```
function phoneContract(brand, model, network, minutes, texts, data, upcost, monthlycost, length) {
    this.brand=brand;
    this.model=model;
    this.network=network;
    this.minutes=minutes;
    this.texts=texts;
    this.data=data;
    this.upcost=upcost;
    this.monthlycost=monthlycost;
    this.length=length;
}
var contract=[];
contract.push(new phoneContract("Motorola", "StarTAC", "Z-Mobile", "300", "3500", "N/A", "0", "5", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Nokia", "3310", "O3", "100", "5000", "N/A", "0", "2", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Apple", "iPhone 5C", "Fodavone", "300", "Unlimited", "250MB", "0", "22", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Apple", "iPhone 5C", "NN", "1000", "Unlimited", "2GB", "49", "34", "18"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Samsung", "Galaxy S5", "O3", "500", "Unlimited", "500MB", "0", "24", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Samsung", "Galaxy S5", "Fodavone", "600", "Unlimited", "1GB", "0", "27", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("LG", "G3", "NN", "1000", "Unlimited", "1GB", "0", "31", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Nokia", "Lumia 925", "Fodavone", "600", "Unlimited", "500MB", "0", "27", "18"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("LG", "Optimus L7 2", "NN", "250", "5000", "500MB", "0", "12", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Sony", "Xperia Z3", "O3", "Unlimited", "Unlimited", "1GB", "79", "38", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Sony", "Xperia Z3", "NN", "Unlimited", "Unlimited", "10GB", "0", "44", "24"));

function checkBrand(){
    var phone
    var brandCheck;
    phone = document.getElementsByClassName("phone");
    for (var i=0;i<phone.length;i++) {
        console.log(phone[i].checked)
        if (phone[i].checked == true) {
            brandCheck = phone[i].value;
        }   
    }
    return brandCheck;
}

function checkNetwork(){
    var network
    var networkCheck
    network = document.getElementsByClassName("network");
    for (var i=0;i<network.length;i++) {
        console.log(network[i].checked)
        if (network[i].checked == true) {
        networkCheck = network[i].value;
        }
    }
    return networkCheck;
}
var button = document.getElementById("search");
button.addEventListener("click", search, false);
var minutes
function slidefunction() {
    minutes = parseInt(slider.value)
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = minutes + " Minutes";
}
var slider = document.getElementById("range.slider");
slider.addEventListener("change", slidefunction, false);

var text
function slid() {
    text = parseInt(sli.value)
    document.getElementById("rata").innerHTML = text + " Text";
}
var sli = document.getElementById("slider.range");
sli.addEventListener("change", slid, false);

function search() {
 var brandCheck=checkBrand();
 var networkCheck=checkNetwork();
var model
model = document.getElementById("phone_model"); //???
var f
f = document.getElementById("internet"); //checkbox
var g
g = document.getElementById("upcost");  //auto
var h
h = document.getElementById("month_cost"); //auto ask
var i
i = document.getElementById("contract_length"); //dropdown
    for (var p=0;p<contract.length;p++) {
        var matches = 0;
var total_number_of_conditions = 10;

if (brandCheck == contract[p].brand) matches += 1;
if (model.value == contract[p].model) matches += 1;
if (networkCheck == contract[p].network) matches += 1;
if (minutes >= contract[p].minutes) matches += 1;
if (text >= contract[p].texts) matches += 1;
if (f.value == contract[p].data) matches += 1;
if (g.value == contract[p].upcost) matches += 1;
if (h.value == contract[p].monthlycost) matches += 1;
if (i.value == contract[p].length) matches += 1;

if (matches > 0) {
    var percentage_matched = 100 * (matches / total_number_of_conditions);
    document.write(contract[p].brand + 
        " " + contract[p].model + 
        " " + contract[p].network + 
        " " + contract[p].minutes + 
        " " + contract[p].texts + 
        " " + contract[p].data + 
        " " + contract[p].upcost + 
        " " + contract[p].monthlycost + 
        " " + contract[p].length + 
        " " + percentage_matched + "% </br>");   
}
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `display:none` on the table by default and set it to `display:block` when you find a result. You can set `diplay:none` inline on the element and change it using javascript inside the if statement `if(matches > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

In your function "search()", just before your "for" loop, declare a variable "searchResult", then concatenate each result line in this variable. At the end, put your result in the "main" div :

```
    function search() {
var brandCheck=checkBrand();
 var networkCheck=checkNetwork();
var model
model = document.getElementById("phone_model"); //???
var f
f = document.getElementById("internet"); //checkbox
var g
g = document.getElementById("upcost");  //auto
var h
h = document.getElementById("month_cost"); //auto ask
var i
i = document.getElementById("contract_length"); //dropdown
// Declare your searchResult variable        
var searchResult = "";
        for (var p=0;p<contract.length;p++) {
        var matches = 0;
var total_number_of_conditions = 10;

if (brandCheck == contract[p].brand) matches += 1;
if (model.value == contract[p].model) matches += 1;
if (networkCheck == contract[p].network) matches += 1;
if (minutes >= contract[p].minutes) matches += 1;
if (text >= contract[p].texts) matches += 1;
if (f.value == contract[p].data) matches += 1;
if (g.value == contract[p].upcost) matches += 1;
if (h.value == contract[p].monthlycost) matches += 1;
if (i.value == contract[p].length) matches += 1;
    if (matches > 0) {
        var percentage_matched = 100 * (matches / total_number_of_conditions);
// Concatene lines of the table result
        searchResult += "<tr><td>" + contract[p].brand + 
            "</td><td>" + contract[p].model + 
            "</td><td>" + contract[p].network + 
            "</td><td>" + contract[p].minutes + 
            "</td><td>" + contract[p].texts + 
            "</td><td>" + contract[p].data + 
            "</td><td>" + contract[p].upcost + 
            "</td><td>" + contract[p].monthlycost + 
            "</td><td>" + contract[p].length + 
            "</td><td>" + percentage_matched + "%</td></tr>";   
    }
        }
// Check if there is result
    if(searchResult != ""){
        searchResult = "<table>" + searchResult + "</table>";
    }
// Put the result in the main div
    document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].innerHTML = searchResult;
            }
```

Comment: ok I've got that code but if I select Sony for example output is SonyXperia Z3O3UnlimitedUnlimited1GB79382410%SonyXperia Z3NNUnlimitedUnlimited10GB0442410% and it does it on blank page instead of the div class

Comment: This is the point of this line :

document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].innerHTML = searchResult;

Comment: well yeah i do have that line but it still doesn't work correctly

Comment: And you have replace the "document.write(" by "searchResult +=" ?

Comment: oh no I didn't, now when I have deleted that line, and I choose 'Sony' and press button nothing happens at all

Comment: Well, in the JS file, replace all your search() function as mine.

Comment: Ok it works now, how about if I would like to include a picture of the actual phone? and is there a way to show the results from highest to lowest based on a it's matching percentage?